# Is the phrase "retirement community" is predefined?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, interpretation

Increasing life expectancy has increased the demands for medical care, **retirement communities**, and nursing homes.

I want to know if "retirement communities" is pre-defined, I mean its meaning is predefined or not?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _prefixed_, but the expression has a specific meaning which you can easily look up.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question, what do you mean by "fixed in meaning"? Retirement communities means communities consisting of retired people.

Comment: @KateBunting I want to say it's definition is predefined so one can't say ones own definition of this like in any other case.

Comment: Yes, *retirement communities* is predefined as special places with rules about visitors and such. It is more than a town of senior.

Comment: _Predefined_ just means _defined in advance_, so not relevant here. As I said, it has a specific meaning (communities designed for older people who can still live independently).

Comment: Yours is the kind of question that’s easily resolved by a simple web search. Even Wikipedia has an article that would have settled it for you. Here on ELL it is expected that one try to find answers on one’s own before posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meaning other than it is an area where seniors or retired people live in.

> A retirement community is a residential community or housing complex designed for older adults who are generally able to care for themselves [Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retirement_community)